# wc -l on unix command return value

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a program that when I run it it takes away comments and blank lines etc.

```
/home/user/Development/loc -c /vobs/unitTestStub/works.h
```

And it prints out comment stripped code like

```
#ifndef works_H
#define works_H
#include <fc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
...
```

When I run a

```
wc -l /home/user/Development/loc -c /vobs/unitTestStub/works.h
```

It prints out

```
  56 1349 /home/user/Development/loc
  27  443 /vobs/unitTestStub/works.h
  83 1792 total
```

But I only want wc -l on what the first line returns. For example loc prints out a string that is only 15 lines long and wc -l says that its 27 lines long so this needs to be sorted out.

Can anyone please give me how to run wc -l on what the command

```
wc -l /home/user/Development/loc -c /vobs/unitTestStub/works.h
```

prints out?

Thanks alot in advance =)

Br Anders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pipes for IO redirection:

```
$> /home/user/Development/loc -c /vobs/unitTestStub/works.h | wc -l
```